# Render dynamically a custom Elementor shortcode with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site designed with Elementor where I run code through the html element in Elementor to show a couple of dropdowns, when each one is selected with a value and the button clicked, the values of the dropdowns are passed into variables and then used in a shortcode to be passed to functions.php to run a select query to retrieve info from the database, based on the variables / attributes passed to them through the shortcode. Problem comes in where it is fine to use the shortcode with the parameters already set, but using with the parameter obtained from a variable is not passing through the shortcode (for example it will pass the actual variable name through the shortcode rather than the variable itself). Obviously php is run before javascript so I have read the only way to do this is through an ajax call. Not sure how to do this, please could you assist.

This is how the code is setup:

In the below, if you replace this line of code

```
let shortf = "[my_elementor_php_output455 field_id="shortc" name_id="shorte"]";
```

With

```
let shortf = "[my_elementor_php_output455 field_id="2" name_id="3"]";
```

It would produce the desired results, but it will obviously not pass the variable as in the firast line of code, but rather passes the variable name which is useless, need an ajax call, but need code to assist.

**In the html element in Elementor:**

```
<html> 
<head> 
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body>
<center><label for="InfoPack"><b>Please choose your id</b></label><br>
<select name="InfoPack" id="InfoPack">
    
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6/option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8/option>
  </select></center>
  
  <center><label for="InfoPack1"><b>Please choose your name</b></label><br>
<select name="InfoPack1" id="InfoPack1">
    
  <option value="1">Moe</option>
  <option value="2">Dooley</option>
  <option value="3">Finn</option>
  <option value="4">James</option>
  <option value="5">Doe</option>
  <option value="6">Stanley/option>
  <option value="7">Day</option>
  <option value="8">Jay/option>
  </select></center>
  
    <button id="button"> process !</button> 
   <p> 
      <div id="result"> </div> 
   </p> 
   
   <script> 

      $(document).ready(function() { 
         $('#button').click(function() {
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
         let shortc = "";
         let shorte = "";
         let shortf = "";
            fun(); 
         }); 
      }); 

     function fun() { 
       let shortc = document.getElementById("InfoPack").value;
       let shorte = document.getElementById("InfoPack1").value;
       let shortf = "[my_elementor_php_output455 field_id="shortc" name_id="shorte"]";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = shortf;
      } 
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**In the functions.php:**

```
// Shortcode to output custom PHP in Elementor
function wpc_elementor_shortcode455( $atts, $content = null, $tag){
$atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'field_id'     => '',
            'name_id'     => '',
        ],
        $atts
    );

$myshape = $atts['field_id'];
$myshape1 = $atts['name_id'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, nid, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests where id=$myshape AND nid=$myshape1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result !== false && $result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      
    return "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  return "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: The shortcode gets parsed on the server side. You can not "insert" client-side variables into it like that.

Comment: That it where an ajax call could assist if I am correct? Could you perhaps share an example of how I could achieve this with an ajax call or similar manner? Thanks

Comment: Set up an AJAX endpoint in WP, that takes the parameters passed from the frontend, creates the shortcode string by inserting those, and then calls `do_shortcode` to get the whole thing evaluated. Echo the result back to the client.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, could you perhaps supply example code for the ajax call in javascript and then the function in functions.php to execute the passed parameters from the frontend. Sorry, being trying to do the ajax call for a few days now without success, not sure about the coding for this process actually. Thanks

Comment: Can't give you a complete run-down of how AJAX works in WP in just a few lines here now; if you are not familiar with the concept, then try and work through an explanation such as f.e. https://medium.com/@alejandro-ao/how-to-do-ajax-in-wordpress-a826f9fde4d5

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I tried to understand the ajax, I posted an answer below, when I click the button, nothing happens, maybe you can see an error.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec unless I am misunderstanding something here, they want the shortcode output with an argument, that only gets determined on the client side. So they will need to send that value to the server, so that the shortcode can get rendered there.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, as per CBroe, the shortcode will execute, but the problem is that it does not accept the variables. Instead, it will pass the variables as the name itself, so it will pass shortc and shorte as the name itself to the function which will render the result as "o results" due to the fact that it is not getting the value of the variable. In order for the values to be sent to the server, you have to do an ajax call, which I tried below, but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code replacement *(uses Ajax to render the shortcode dynamically*)

HTML + jQuery (Elementor):

```html
<html> 
<head> 
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body>
<center>
<label for="infopack-id"><b>Please choose your id</b></label><br>
<select name="InfoPack" id="infopack-id">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6/option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8/option>
</select>
</center>
<center>
<label for="infopack-name"><b>Please choose your name</b></label><br>
<select name="InfoPack1" id="infopack-name">
  <option value="1">Moe</option>
  <option value="2">Dooley</option>
  <option value="3">Finn</option>
  <option value="4">James</option>
  <option value="5">Doe</option>
  <option value="6">Stanley/option>
  <option value="7">Day</option>
  <option value="8">Jay/option>
</select>
</center>
<button id="button">Process !</button> 
<p> 
  <div id="result"> </div> 
</p> 

<script> 
jQuery(function($) { 
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        const id   = $('#infopack-id').val(),
              name = $('#infopack-name').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: window.location.origin+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
                'action': 'render_shortcode', 
                'id'    : id, 
                'name'  : name
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP *(functions.php file)*

```php
// Receive and process the ajax request
add_action('wp_ajax_render_shortcode', 'render_shortcode_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_render_shortcode', 'render_shortcode_callback');
function render_shortcode_callback() {
    if ( isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['name']) ) {
        $id = esc_attr($_POST['id']);
        $name = esc_attr($_POST['name']);
        echo do_shortcode("[my_elementor_php_output455 field_id='{$id}' name_id='{$name}']");
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

and your shortcode function (untested and unchanged):

```php
// Shortcode to output custom PHP in Elementor
function wpc_elementor_shortcode455( $atts, $content = null, $tag){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( [
        'field_id'     => '',
        'name_id'     => '',
    ], $atts );
    
    $myshape = $atts['field_id'];
    $myshape1 = $atts['name_id'];
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx";
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT id, nid, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests where id=$myshape AND nid=$myshape1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    if ($result !== false && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            return "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        return "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Tested with a custom shortcode and works, displaying the shortcode dynamically.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec, do you perhaps have a link I can follow to see how your test was done with your custom shortcode. On my side, I did try the above, but after clicking the button, it is like it is not doing the Ajax call, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Hum, sorry, I have tested that locally with a custom shortcode, as I don't use Elementor… You need to be sure that your shortcode works and display something when you set the parameters manually. My code works based on your provided HTML code structure.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, I managed to get it to work, thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the codes you shared for me , there is multiple syntax issue.
could you share the URL ?

Comment: Thanks Kokkhta, I have tried this though with the same result. The result is "o results" in my div which shows that the shortcode is run, but what is passed to functions.php is the actual name "shortc" and "shorte". If I do a return on the variable in the shortcode, it show the result as shortc and shorte, the actual words not the variable. So the shortcode does actually run, although not as intended, so the problem is not running the shortcode, but trying to find a way to get the variables into functions.php from Javascript, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I have tried adding ajax without success, when I click on the button, nothing happens, probably formatting, not sure at all, here is the code:

Javascript:

```
<script> 
   

             $(document).ready(function() { 
             $('#button').click(function() {
             ajaxcall();
    
    });
    
    });
       
       
    function ajaxCall() {
        let shorto = document.getElementById("InfoPack").value;
                $.ajax({
               type: "post",
               url: `${window.location.origin}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`,
               data: {
               action: "my_action",  // the action to fire in the server
               data: shorto,         // any JS object
      },
     complete: function (response) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = console.log(JSON.parse(response.responseText).data);
     },
    
    });
                    
    }             
    
       </script>
```

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_function');
function my_function() {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $data1 = "[my_elementor_php_output455 field_id=".$data." name_id=3]";
    wp_send_json_success($data1);
}
```

Comment: This is currently not an answer to the question that was asked here - so please do not post it _as_ an answer. Edit your question, and include the code there. Thanks!